# Необходимо ли в python вызывать return в конце функции если в конце вызывается другая функция?

Tags: python, функции, рекурсия, return

Делаю игру на `pygame` и в конце почти каждой функции вызывается другая функция. Сама игра проходит в функции `mainloop()`, при проигрыше вызывается `end_game()`, в конце неё вызывается `call_menu()`, оттуда вызывается  `game_resume()`, там обновляются элементы и вызывается `mainloop()`, игра продолжается. То есть нет шагов назад, как в обычном скрипте.

**Могут ли быть проблемы** если не использовать `return` в конце при таком циклическом вызове? Типа **переполнения памяти** или ошибки из-за **превышения глубины рекурсии**, хоть это и не совсем рекурсия. Нужно ли в конце каждой функции писать `return next_function()` для вызова следующей функции? Или при таком циклическом вызове `return` не имеет значения?

```
def mainloop(self):
    self.end_game()

def end_game(self):
    self.call_menu()

def call_menu(self):
    self.game_resume()

def game_resume(self):
    self.mainloop()  # Возвращение в функцию с главным циклом
```

Comment: не обязательно, но не забываем, что рекурсия может вызвать сбой или ошибку прям большом заполнении в памяти

Comment: в python все функции по умолчанию return'ят None. Так что нет

Comment: @AleksandrFetisov в том то и вопрос - без `return` возможно ли теоретически переполнить память? и вообще задействуется ли избыточная память в таком случае? с `return` насколько я понимаю это физически не возможно сделать таким вызовом функций

Comment: без return память забьется да

Comment: @AliakseiLz это если код дойдет до конца функции. Но если в её теле вызывается другая функция, то исполнение переходит в неё. И, насколько я понимаю, исходная функция не завершает свою работу, код не доходит до автоматического `return None` в конце

Comment: @AleksandrFetisov вот в этом и есть суть вопроса. видимо`return` обязателен, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще-то у вас именно рекурсия, просто функция не сразу сама себя вызывает, а опосредованно через несколько других функций. Рано или поздно такой подход закончится тем, что исчерпается максимальная глубина рекурсии и код упадёт. Поэтому конкретно в вашем примере лучше сделать как-то так, чтобы не было рекурсии. То есть добавить основную функцию, которая будет в цикле что-то делать и вызывать другие функции.

```py
def main(self):
    while True:
        self.mainloop()
        new_state = self.call_menue()
        if new_state == 'exit':
            break
        elif new_state == 'resume':
            self.resume_game()

def mainloop(self):
     self.end_game()

def end_game(self):
    # убираем вызов меню, просто меняем состояние игры
    # self.call_menu()

def call_menu(self):
    # убираем вызов, оставляем сам выбор из меню
    # self.game_resume()
    return <что было выбрано>

def game_resume(self):
    # убираем вызов, просто меняем состояние игры
    # self.mainloop()  # Возвращение в функцию с главным циклом
```

Comment: мои эксперименты показали, что и мой изначальный вариант, и вариант с `return next_function()` в конце каждой функции одинаково вызывают рекурсию. чтобы этого избежать мне придется переписать часть кода, вы правы... спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Не обязательно, но для спокойствия можете сделать return в каждой функции, что то на подобии:

```
def mainloop(self):
    return self.end_game()

def end_game(self):
    return self.call_menu()

def call_menu(self):
    return self.game_resume()

def game_resume(self):
    return self.mainloop()  # Возвращение в функцию с главным циклом
```

Comment: а какие подводные камни без `return`? выше подсказали, что память все таки может забиться. в таком случае `return` обязателен, разве нет?

Comment: Так глубоко не изучал, что питон делает с памятью. Но мне кажется, что в вашем случае функция из которой вызвана следующая функция будет ожидать выполнения, и логика питона захочет вернуться в исходную функцию, чтобы проверить закончилась ли она, но не сможет из-за непрерывной рекурсии. Возможно в этом заключаются опасения в комменте выше.

Comment: От того, что вы добавили `return` рекурсия из кода не пропала, этот `return` никогда не сработает, так и будет по кругу ходить.